# How libevent triggers callback

Tags: c, sockets, libevent

I am wondering how libevent triggers the callback. For example, let's say a client repeatedly sends a 4-byte message. In server's side, it seems not each 4-byte send will trigger a read callback. For example, I found the callback is sometimes triggered at a point of receiving 8-byte message (or other number). Is it possible to configure the libevent such that the read callback on server's side is triggered for each 4-byte message sent from the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is about sending, not about receiving. Libevent is probably not sending your data **immediately** because of **output buffering**, thus your `read` callback is only invoked when the client really receives the data you've sent.

See **[Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)** (aka `TCP_NODELAY`). Then try disabling it to see if that's really the case:

```
int flag = 1;
int ret = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &flag, sizeof(flag));
```

> Is it possible to configure the libevent such that the read callback on server's side is triggered for each 4-byte message sent from the client?

Not really. You may receive multiple messages "simultaneously" as TCP is a stream-oriented protocol. Your application's only concern is to know where each message starts and ends.

Disregarding libevent for the purpose of explanation, you'd normally:

1. Keep calling `recv` in a loop;
2. Append the received data/payload to a buffer;
3. Invoke a method to process that buffer;
4. The process method checks the buffer size to see if it contains at least 1 full message. In your case, you want it to be at least 4 bytes, so you know you have at least 1 full message to process. If your buffer has a size that's not a multiple of 4 bytes (which should never happen given the very small size of your payload), say 10 bytes, you process the initial 4 bytes, remove them from the buffer, repeat once again, and then keep the remaining 2 bytes in the buffer.

Comment: I see. Is it possible for server to receive a message with size not being multiple of 4?

Comment: Keeping in mind your payload is exactly 4-byte long, then the answer is NO, but of course I don't recommend relying on this. You better use a mechanism to store received data (see [bufferevent's](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref6_bufferevent.html)) and later process it. If you detect you haven't received a full message, then you should just wait for more.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense this way.